Enviroment variables for a cloud build configuration file deploying a laravel app
I have a PHP laravel 10 app which I am trying to deploy on GAE, I have created the following simple cloud build trigger and chose inline file mode.
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    env:
      - 'APP_NAME=${_APP_NAME}'
    args:
      - app
      - deploy
timeout: 1600s

The build process completes successfully, but unfortunately, my app doesn’t seem to receive the environment variable that I pass in the substitute variable section. I’ve even attempted to remove that environment variable from the app.yaml file, but the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!


In your app.yaml, you should use build_env_variables or env_variables [1].
[1]. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=php#top
